# OCaml Binding a variable with nested types

Tags: types, nested, ocaml

I am new to OCaml and am trying to jump into a large OCaml project. While tracing through the types that make up other types I was trying to think how I would use these, so I broke it down to a small example that I think is pretty close to how it is in the larger project.

If I have the record type `expression` made of three fields:

```
type expression = {e_id:int; e_node:exp_node; e_loc:location}
and exp_node =
  | Const of int
  | Lval of lval
  | SizeofStr of string
and lval =
  | Var of varinfo
  | Mem of expression
and location = {x:int; y:int}
and varinfo = {vname:string; vorigname:string}
```

I can bind a variable of this type if the `e_node` field is an integer:

```
let exp_const = {e_id=10;
                 e_node= Const 10;
                 e_loc={x=10; y=10}}
```

Now if I want that `e_node` field to be of the `Lval` type which is the record type `lval` I can not figure out how to do it. I tried:

```
let exp_lval_var =
  {e_id=11;
   e_node= {vname="int_val"; vorigname="int_val1"};
   e_loc={x=10; y=20}}
```

But it says that `This expression has type varinfo but an expression was expected of type exp_node`. But if you follow the types, it is!?

Am I not defining types correctly here? Or am I not using the types correctly? I couldn't really find many more complex examples of using OCaml types. Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you wrote `Const 10` (as opposed to just `10`), you need to write `Lval (Var { ... })` to get the right kind of value for your `e_node` field.

```
let exp_lval_var =
  {e_id=11;
   e_node= Lval (Var {vname="int_val"; vorigname="int_val1"});
   e_loc={x=10; y=20}}
```

To follow the types for the first example:

- `10` is of type `int`
- `Const 10` is of type `exp_node`

For the second example

- `{vname="int_val"; vorigname="int_val1"}` is of type `varinfo`
- `Var {vname="int_val"; vorigname="int_val1"}` is of type `lval`
- `Lval (Var {vname="int_val"; vorigname="int_val1"})` is of type `exp_node`

Value constructors like `Const`, `Var`, and `Lval` are not just labels for documentation in OCaml. They must appear as part of the expression to make a value of their type.

Comment: Thank You! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: so then with my `exp_lval_var` if I have that and want to access the `vname` associated with it, I would want to have a function to grab that out? It wouldn't be very Ocaml idiomatic to do something where I traverse the types to grab the `vname` record element in place, like in the argument to a `Printf.printf "%s"` for example? (I realize that side-effects aren't really idiomatic either as they are side-effects)

Comment: Would a function like this be the best bet:

let get_vname {e_id=_; e_node=node; e_loc=_} = match node with
  | Const i -> Printf.sprintf "e_node is int: %i (no vname)" i
  | Lval lv -> (match lv with
    | Var {vname=vstring; vorigname=vostring} -> Printf.sprintf "%s to %s" vostring vstring
    | Mem _ -> "have expression")
  | SizeofStr sizestr -> Printf.sprintf "e_node is SizeofStr: %s (no vname)" sizestr
Then I could use it like `Printf.printf "%s" (get_vname exp_lval_var);;`

Comment: Actually I see I could make that function recursive for the case of `Mem`